# FFMPEG libraries segfault on Android -- C# UNITY

Tags: c#, android, ffmpeg

I got a unity project which has to run on Android and Windows. To be able to decode raw H264 frames, I am using a ffmpeg wrapper, It works great on Windows but on Android I get a segmentation fault on av_log_default_callback, called by avcodec_decode_video2.

here is the backtrace :

```
05-26 10:47:45.224 24270 24286 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 
1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 24286 (UnityMain)
05-26 10:47:45.224   463   463 W         : debuggerd: handling request: 
pid=24270 uid=10152 gid=10152 tid=24286
05-26 10:47:45.332 24535 24535 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-26 10:47:45.332 24535 24535 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
05-26 10:47:45.333 24535 24535 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
05-26 10:47:45.333 24535 24535 F DEBUG   : pid: 24270, tid: 24286, name: 
UnityMain  >>> com.my.app <<<
05-26 10:47:45.333 24535 24535 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 
(SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
05-26 10:47:45.333 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     r0 cf444220  r1 00000000  r2 
00010000  r3 00000000
05-26 10:47:45.333 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     r4 e9254b1c  r5 00000010  r6 
e9254b14  r7 e9255c90
05-26 10:47:45.333 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     r8 c860f670  r9 cf444220  sl 
e925531c  fp e9254f1c
05-26 10:47:45.333 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     ip 000003f0  sp e9254ac0  lr 
cffa5518  pc 00000000  cpsr a8010010
05-26 10:47:45.339 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :
05-26 10:47:45.339 24535 24535 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
05-26 10:47:45.339 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00000000  <unknown>
05-26 10:47:45.339 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00018514  
/data/app/com.my.app/lib/arm/libavutil-55.so
05-26 10:47:45.339 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 000189f4  
/data/app/com.my.app/lib/arm/libavutil-55.so 
(av_log_default_callback+168)
05-26 10:47:45.339 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00018d38  
/data/app/com.my.app/lib/arm/libavutil-55.so (av_log+80)
05-26 10:47:45.339 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 001bf538  
/data/app/com.my.app/lib/arm/libavcodec-57.so
05-26 10:47:45.339 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 001c4eac  
/data/app/com.my.app/lib/arm/libavcodec-57.so 
05-26 10:47:45.339 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 0038cce0  
/data/app/com.my.app/lib/arm/libavcodec-57.so 
(avcodec_decode_video2+380)
05-26 10:47:45.339 24535 24535 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00003490  
<anonymous:cb624000>
```

I had to replace pointers by refs in the prototypes of the imported ffmpeg functions, to fix a Marshal error saying structs are not blittable and that I should use refs instead :

```
avcodec_decode_video2(AVCodecContext *ctx, AVFrame *frame, int *gotPicture,......);
```

became :

```
avcodec_decode_video2(ref AVCodecContext ctx, ref AVFrame frame, ref int gotPicture,.......);
```

everything works fine on Windows, using refs instead of pointer had no incidence and functions are now correctly imported on Android.

If anyone has infos that could be helpful to my research or know someone who had this bug, please share thank you !